# How to unblock websites with batch using hosts file

Tags: batch-file, hosts

I used the following code:

```
echo 127.0.0.1 drive.google.com >> C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

in a batch file. The only way to unblock it is to open the hosts file with notepad and edit it. I was wondering if there is a way you can use batch to delete all the text on the hosts file but not the file itself.

Comment: `echo. >C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to blank the whole file, see @pupa-rebbe's comment.

```
echo. >%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

If you want to be more selective, and unblock just one host without wiping out anything else in the file, you can use the output of `findstr /v`

```
pushd %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
copy hosts hosts.bak
findstr /v /c:"drive.google.com" hosts.bak > hosts
popd
```